# How to select 20 random questions from each set in sql?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I am working on **online** question application.

I am Fetching Records from a **database**.

I have `SQL database` holding **1000** question in **10** set. I mean each set containing 100 questions. How can I take **20 random questions** from each set? I mean how can I select **2** (as per request) random question from each set?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM [YourTable] ORDER By NEWID()
```

More About [NEWID()](http://learnsqlserver.in/3/NewId-function.aspx).

Comment: This will retrieve 20 random rows, not 2 random rows per set.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get 20 random questions **from each group** here is an [**SQLFiddle example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a767c/12). `SetNum` here is a set ID

```
select * from 
(
select t.*, 
ROW_NUMBER() 
over (partition by setNum order by NewId()) rNum from t
) t2 where rNum<=20
```

Comment: +1 You'd need `rowNum <= 2` though, for the first two per set

Comment: @Andomar  `where rNum<=20` selects 20 questions per set as a topic starter required. So you can write `where rNum<=2`

Comment: The question ends with "I mean how can I select 2 (as per request) random question from each set?"  But the line before that is definitely ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want `2` random questions from each SET...

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM (SELECT * FROM [YourTable] WHERE SET_ID = 1) ORDER By NEWID()
UNION
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM (SELECT * FROM [YourTable] WHERE SET_ID = 2) ORDER By NEWID()
UNION
.
.
.
.
UNION
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM (SELECT * FROM [YourTable] WHERE SET_ID = 10) ORDER By NEWID()
```